# reverse numbers in a specific range backwards using a function in python

Tags: python, function, numbers, range

```
def positive_range(start, end):
    for num in range(start, end + 1):           # +1 counts the last number in range
        if num >= 0:
            print(num)

positive_range(-18, 8)


def reverse_positive_range(start, end):
    for num in range(start, end + 1):
        if num >= 0:
            print(num)
            num -= 1

reverse_positive_range(9, -8)
```

For the first function:

My objective was to use a function to find the positive numbers in a specific range.

But for the second function:

My objective was to do the same thing as the first function shown above, but to do it in reverse order for the positive numbers in the range only.

Like `8, 7, 6, 5, 4, etc.` I tried attempting it as shown below, but it's not right code. How do I go of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`range` takes an optional thrid argument of the step to take between each member. Setting it to a negative will make the range move "backwards" from a large number down to the smaller one:

```py
def reverse_positive_range(start, end):
    for num in range(end + 1, start, -1):
        if num >= 0:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik for answering my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: One thing needs to be pointed out is in this case - *start* should be less than *end* - like:  ```reverse_positive(-8, 9)```